# Birth dates vs. Due dates

Tags: data-request, medical, biology

Are there any resources out there to estimate the distribution of actual birth dates vs due dates?  I would like to do an analysis similar to [this](http://spacefem.com/pregnant/charts/duedate0.php).

Comment: I'm not sure where this data came from, and it's not exactly what you're looking for, but perhaps it will give you some additional sources to consider: [Birthday patterns in the US](http://www.reddit.com/r/dataisbeautiful/comments/2grn2k/birthday_patterns_in_the_us_oc/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allen Downey's free online book [Think Stats](http://greenteapress.com/thinkstats/html/index.html) uses data from the [National Survey of Family Growth](http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/nsfg.htm) to consider the question "Do First Babies Arrive Late?"

[Section 1.3 of the book](http://greenteapress.com/thinkstats/html/thinkstats002.html#htoc5) explains some use of the data. There is a [newer version of the dataset (2006-2010)](http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/nsfg/nsfg_2006_2010_puf.htm) on the NSFG site.